# Android intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra on ArrayList<LatLng> raises Nullpointer exception

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass an array list of LatLng objects to another activity. The method is defined in a Util class which is not an activity. But the receiving activity always raises `NullpointerException`

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        fun startMaps(pairs: MutableList<LatLng>){
            var intent = Intent(AAddressActivity.appContext, MapActivity::class.java)
            Log.d("pair", ArrayList(pairs).toString())
            Log.d("pair", ArrayList(pairs)[0].toString())
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList(pairs))

            AAddressActivity.appContext.startActivity(intent)
        }
}
```

`Log.d` prints the content of the pairs which are not empty. /// `AAddressActivity.appContext` where AAddressActivity is the activity calling the `Utils.startMap()` method, and `appContext` is defined as

```
companion object{
        lateinit  var appContext: Context
    }
```

and initialized in the `onCreate() AAddressActivity` as `appContext=this` to allow external access to the context of `AAddressActivity`.
This is the receiving activity:

```
class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    lateinit var latLngList: ArrayList<LatLng>
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)


        // Error happens here
        latLngList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("key", LatLng::class.java)!!
        Log.d("longMap", latLngList[0].toString())

    }
```

Error is

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidapplicationproject/com.example.androidapplicationproject.mapUtil.MapActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isInterface()' on a null object reference
```

As far as I know, LatLng object implements Parcelable so I shouldn't worry about that. But why is the error happening? How do I fix it.

I just found that if there are only ONE element in the `pairs` then the `MapActivity` can successfully receive the parcel, but if there are two or more elements in the list, the exception raises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the issue and since it didn't seem like there was anything wrong with the code, I [googled for "parcelablearraylist bug"](https://www.google.com/search?q=getparcelablearraylistextra%20bug) and found [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/y25bdy/getparcelable_depreciated_googling_not_led_me_to/) that had [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/y25bdy/comment/is1pdts/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that linked to [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930) where a Google Engineer [acknowledges it's a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930#comment6).

So to answer the question:

> But why is the error happening?

It's a bug with the new methods that take a `Class` argument.

> How do I fix it.

Stick to the old methods that don't take a `Class` parameter (like [getParcelableArrayListExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String))) until the bug is fixed or they release a Compat version of the API that will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just curious to know what's the 'old methods' you mentioned? Should I use different way to pass a list of <LatLng> to other activities? if so, could you give some keywords so I can do my research?

Comment: Using old methods solve the problem.. Didn't realize it's a bug. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you found the answer, but I updated the answer to include a link to the old method for posterity.